# Сортировка постов по просмотрам.Tthrive - theme

Tags: wordpress, сортировка

Есть покупная тема с thrivethemes. Есть некий визуальный редактор, похож на элементор. Есть возможность создать некое поле и вывести в него превью (картинку с заголовком) поста. Эти превью выводятся отсортированными по дате, количеству комментов и т.д. Необходимо вывести эти посты по просмотрам.
Счетчик просмотров был не предусмотрен в теме, удалось добавить его. Теперь счетчик отрабатывает.
В коде темы слишком большое количество некомментированного кода, найти функции сортировки не удалось.
Понимаю что подсказать как это реализовать вряд ли кто-нибудь сможет, слишком мало информации. Но накидайте мне идей, как такое можно реализовать. Может фильтрами, не меняя ничего в теме, может с этими темами кто-нибудь работал?

Comment: Любые изменения в теме надо производить через дочернюю тему. В противном случае вы лишаете себя возможности получать обновления, а они могут быть критичными по безопасности.

Comment: Конкретные решения, не видя кода темы, никто подсказать не сможет.

Comment: 1. Функционал, которым и является счётчик просмотров, делается плагинами, а не "в теме".  2. Полно готовых плагинов для этого.

Comment: В реализации просмотров нет ничего сложного. Нужно реализовать сортировку выведеных постов в специальном блоке. В простых темах это делает простой луп, там все понятно как сделать. Именно в этой теме все усложненно.
Напишите пожалуйста конкретное предложение и я попробую его применить. Плагины с просмотрами никак с этим выводом постов не взаимодействуют.

Comment: Подключите к своему WP Medoo для работы с базой и наслаждайтесь скоростью и простотой решения таких задач. https://medoo.in/api/new